# Mysql results not storing on a file

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have a mysql statement and I would like to store the data it fetches in a csv file in tab format. I have used the following statment but it is not creating and storing the results when I run my file and no error files.

```
  $mytry =  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `assigned` = '$id'
    INTO OUTFILE '/inactive/orders.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

    mysql_query($mytry);
```

Or there a way I can write to file in a directory without prompting the user to download, this works but it prompts

```
    $sQuery="SELECT * FROM table WHERE `assigned` = '$id'";

$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or die();
$count = mysql_num_fields($rResult);

$html = '<table border="1"><thead><tr>%s</tr><thead><tbody>%s</tbody></table>';
$thead = '';
$tbody = '';
$line = '<tr>%s</tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){      
  $thead .= sprintf('<th>%s</th>',mysql_field_name($rResult, $i));
}


while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rResult))){
  $trow = '';

  foreach($row as $value){
   $trow .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value);
  }

  $tbody .= sprintf($line, $trow);

}


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

print sprintf($html, $thead, $tbody);
exit;
```

Comment: `mysql_query` executes the query. Do you want to store the query itself or the data that it returns?

Comment: Keep in mind that the output file must not already exist and that the user MySQL is running as has write permissions to the directory MySQL is attempting to write the file to.

Comment: Is there other script I can use to write to file without prompting the user to download

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You must write to the file directly from your script. Read my answer below.

Comment: Are you trying to store the file on the client or server? The first query stores it on the server, the second one downloads it to the client. It's not possible to put a file on the client without prompting the user to download, that would be a security violation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the following PHP function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Fetch the data using your query and then save it to a variable. Then, use `fputcsv` to store the data to a file.

Also, I would discourage the usage of `mysql_query`, since it has now become **deprecated** (as well as the rest of `mysql_*` family). Furthermore, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Read up on using [PDO for database interaction](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Some more recommended reading to put you on the right track: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

**EDIT:** From what you have shown in your code sample, you simply output an HTML page to the browser, which gets downloaded right away because of the `Content-Disposition` header you set.